# Does Rich Faces AjaxValidator work with selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf, richfaces

Folks,

This is a JSF question, specifically for Rich Faces 3.3.3.Final

I am trying to get the Rich Faces Ajax Validator (rich:ajaxValidator) to work with a standard JSF drop down menu (h:selectOneMenu) but I'm failing miserably.

Basically I want AJAX validation to happen when the drop down loses focus or an item in the drop down is selected. Below is code for the last thing I tried:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="sector" value="#{thing.sector}">  
  <f:selectItems value="#{selectItemMap['sectors']}"  
                 var="sector"  
                 itemLabel="#{msg[sector.itemLabel]}"  
                 itemValue="#{sector.itemValue}" />  
    <rich:ajaxValidator event="onblur"/>  
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

But I've also tried:

```
<rich:ajaxValidator event="oninputblur"/>
```

and

```
<rich:ajaxValidator event="onchange"/>
```

and

```
<rich:ajaxValidator event="onchanged"/>
```

and

```
     <rich:ajaxValidator event="onblur"/>  
<rich:ajaxValidator event="onchanged"/>
```

and

```
<rich:ajaxValidator event="onblur"/>  
<rich:ajaxValidator event="onchange"/>
```

and

```
<rich:ajaxValidator event="oninputblur"/>  
<rich:ajaxValidator event="onchange"/>
```

and

```
<rich:ajaxValidator event="oninputblur"/>  
<rich:ajaxValidator event="onchanged"/>
```

However, none of these work. By which I mean that I can't see anything happening, although I can see events being handled in my log console for other fields like h:inputText, standard HTML input and rich:calendar.

Has anyone managed to get Rich Faces AJAX validation working for the selectOneMenu field and how did you it? Oh and for what version of Rich Faces?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample from my old app using Richfaces 3.3:

```
<h:selectOneMenu
    id="users"
    value="#{userBean.user}"
    required="true"
    requiredMessage="Selected user is required."
    converter="selectItemConverter">
    <rich:ajaxValidator ajaxSingle="true" event="onchange" />
    <f:validator validatorId="isValidValidator" />
    <t:selectItems 
        value="#{userBean.users}"
        var="user" 
        itemLabel="#{user.name}"
        itemValue="#{user}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
<rich:message for="users" errorClass="error"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Doh!

The following DOES work:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="subSector" value="#{registerContracts.currentContract.subSector}">
  <f:selectItems value="#{selectItemMap['RctSectorTypes']}" var="subSector" itemLabel="#{msg[subSector.itemLabel]}" itemValue="#{subSector.itemValue}" />
  <rich:ajaxValidator event="onblur"/>
  <rich:ajaxValidator event="onchange"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

I obviously wasn't diligent enough in testing out the above-mentioned options.

Sorry about that.